# Basis Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Find a basis of the subspace $U = \langle x^2 −x +4, x −1, x^2 +x \rangle$ of the vector space $P_2$ over $\Bbb R$ of all polynomials of degree at most $2$.

Am I being stupid? I checked for linear independence by placing in a matrix and it had $3$ pivots, so since al $3$ vector polynomials are linearly independent and $P_2$ has dimension $3$, then these polynomials also span $P_2$ and hence form a basis of dimension $3$?

Comment: Yes, $U=P_2$ and hence the  given three generators of $U$ form a basis (and so do $1,x,x^2$ etc.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Cheers. Is there a way I could spot that $U = \mathbb P _2$ straight away or would I just use the method I stated?